# How to remove the shipping flat rate for particular products in Drupal commerce kickstart?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, commerce

I am using [Commerce kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart). I have to add the products for category wise. Categories are DVD,Audio CD and edownload.I have to use term reference field for field_category in the products content types.

Now the user purchase the edownload products means shipping charge should be 0rs. How to set the edownload term reference field products for shipping charge is 0. Anyone guide to me?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these modules:

1. [Commerce Discount Product Category](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_product_category)
2. [Commerce Discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount)